# Python print statement shows unwanted characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, printf

I am new to python and am having difficulties with an assignment for a class.

Here's my code:

```
print ('Plants for each semicircle garden: ',round(semiPlants,0))
```

Here's what gets printed:

```
('Plants for each semicircle garden:', 50.0)
```

As you see I am getting the parenthesis and apostrophes, which I do not want shown.

Comment: If this were python 2.x, I would say you are printing a tuple. Run python --version and make sure you are 3.x

Comment: @JoshRagem -- And I would say this is python2.x ;^)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're clearly using python2.x when you think you're using python3.x.  In python 2.x, the stuff in the parenthesis is being interpreted as a `tuple`.

One fix is to use string formatting to do this:

```
print ( 'Plants for each semicircle garden: {0}'.format(round(semiPlants,0)))
```

which will work with python2.6 and onward (parenthesis around a single argument aren't interpreted as a `tuple`.  To get a 1-tuple, you need to do `(some_object,)`)

Answer (score 2):

You've tagged this question Python-3.x, but it looks like you are actually running your code with Python 2.

To see what version you're using, run, "python -V".

Answer (score 2):

Remove the parentheses as print is a statement, not a function in Python 2.x:

```
print 'Plants for each semicircle garden: ',round(semiPlants,0)



Plants for each simicircle garden:  50.0
```